# OpenCV 1.1, IplImage can not show image correctly

Tags: c, opencv

I had a strange problem using OpenCV. Assume I have a CHAR type memory block, which is a buffer for a 8bit depth image with sizeX*sizeY. The pointer to the image is called pcMask, so I save the buffer to a file called mask.dat using the following code:

```
char fpath[256] = ".\mask.dat";
FILE *pFile = 0;
pFile = fopen(fpath,"wb");
if (pFile) {
    fwrite(pcMask, sizeof(char), sizeX * sizeY, pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
    pFile = 0;
}
```

right after saving the mask.dat, i called Opencv APIs to display the image as following:

```
IplImage *mask = cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(sizeY,sizeX), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
mask->imageData = pcMask;
// display image 
cvNamedWindow("test", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvShowImage("test", mask);
cvWaitKey(0);
cvDestroyWindow("test");
cvReleaseImageHeader(&mask);
```

I actually know how the image should look like. to verify that, i wrote a python script to load the "mask.dat" file and imshowed it using matplotlib, and it looks fine like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jdyL.png), however, the image displayed using OpenCV differs alot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7FW4.jpg) (not the color map). As you can see, the ellipses in the two figures are totally different. As they are using the data from the same memory block, should they be the same?

thanks alot!

**UPDATES:**
i now think there is a bug in OpenCV1.1, 'cus I changed IplImage to CvMat, and everything is fine now

```
CvMat *mask = cvCreateMatHeader(sizeY,sizeX, CV_8UC1);
mask->data.ptr = pcMask;
// display image 
cvNamedWindow("test", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvShowImage("test", mask);
cvWaitKey(0);
cvDestroyWindow("test");
cvReleaseImageHeader(&mask);
```

OpenCV2.X might not have such issue, but I can only use 1.1 to keep consistence with the whole program. Anyway, I now use CvMat as my solution.

Comment: If you move to the OpenCV 2 API you will save years off your life. I would have thought using CvMat would cause more inconsistency than linking to a less buggy version of the library. But skip CvMat and use cv::Mat.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#cvsize):

> CvSize cvSize(int width, int height)

Therefore

```
IplImage *mask = cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(sizeY, sizeX), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
```

should be

```
IplImage *mask = cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(sizeX, sizeY), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
```

**EDIT**

You should not set `mask->imageData` directly, but use [`cvSetData()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvsetdata#void%20cvSetData%28CvArr%2a%20arr,%20void%2a%20data,%20int%20step%29):

```
cvSetData(mask, pcMask, sizeY);
```

Comment: I tested by switching sizeX and sizeY, that mess up the whole image and the ellipse is completely gone, so i am sure cvSize(sizeY, sizeX) is correct.

Comment: @shelper if you have followed the normal convetions for X and Y, width is in the X direction and Y is in the height direction, `cvSize(sizeY, sizeX)` is  inxorrect - please read the documentation. There must be another problem in you code.

Answer (score 1):

The angular stretching makes me think that this is an image format/pitch issue. Depending on the situation, the amount of memory occupied by an image may not be equal to `sizeX * sizeY`. Make sure you're not messing up the saving of the image (why not use OpenCV's image saving operations?), and make sure the data you're treating as your image to display is in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for the help, but now i believe this is a bug of OpenCV1.1, please see my new edits in the post, where i used CvMat, and everything is OK